# What are structs initialized as C++

Tags: c++, struct, hashmap

I have a struct that looks like this ...

```
struct Node {
     std::string key, value;
     Node* link;
};
```

If I initialized an array of nodes as such ...

```
Node* linkedlist = new Node[100]
```

How would I iterate over to count how many structs currently exist? I'm implementing a hashmap currently and I need to count how many active buckets there are.

Comment: I don't understand.  If you create an array of 100 nodes then you have 100 nodes.

Comment: But aren't their values not initialized?

Comment: `key` and `value` are .  `link` would have garbage unless you set it to something.

Comment: In C/C++ nothing is initialized unless it has a constructor. You need to explicitly initialize your `link` variables.

Comment: Thanks, so is there a way of checking whether or not something is garbage then? If they're garbage wouldn't that mean the bucket isn't used? I was hoping to have a check for that so I could determine which buckets ARE in use.

Comment: `new` calls `Node() = default` which happens to be `Node() : key{}, value{}, link{} { }`

Comment: @Xari - there is no way to test if a variable is uninitialized. Note - some compilers will initialize variables to 0 in debug builds, and not in release builds.

Comment: If you have a linked list why do you need to create 100 from the start? You can just create them one by one as you need them and so also keep count of them.

Answer (score 1):

> What are structs initialized as C++

When you use

```
Node* linkedlist = new Node[100];
```

all the elements of the array are default initialized. `key` and `value` are default initialized by calling the default constructor of `std::string`. `link` is default initialized, i.e. left uninitialized.

> How would I iterate over to count how many structs currently exist?

You cannot do that given a pointer. That's why `std::vector` is preferred over dynamically allocated raw arrays. You get a lot more functionality with `std::vector`.

Instead of

```
Node* linkedlist = new Node[100];
```

use

```
std::vector<Node> linkedlist(100);
```

**Update, in response to OP's comment**

When you are not allowed to use `std::vector`, you'll have to keep track of the number of items in the array yourself.

```
int numItems = 100; // It could be obtained from the user input also.
Node* linkedlist = new Node[numItems];
```

Now you can rely on the value of `numItems` to iterate over the array of `Node`s in rest of your code.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. I suppose I could just check if the username string is empty and thereby determine if the bucket is used?

Comment: @Xari, my suggestion will be to avoid raw pointer and use `std::vector`.

Comment: Ah, unfortunately my professor is not allowing me to use vectors or smart pointers in this case. Therefore I'm having a hard problem determining how to iterate through my stuff. Usually I make a class for my LinkedList and assign the Node to nullptr.

Comment: I think your professor would also want you to have each link pointer pointing to the next object.